# Processing file line by line, and keeping the line order in output

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm writing a NodeJS route where the user uploads a file (buffer), it is processed line by line (which needs to call a RESP API to process each line) and then outputs the result into another buffer, sent to the user as a download file.

This is the route code:

```
app.post('/tokenizeFile', isLoggedIn, upload.single('file'), function(req, res){
        var file = req.file;

        //File Validations
        if (!validator.validateFile(file)) res.redirect('/?err=invalidFile');

        //Process file
        tokenizer.tokenizeFile(file, req).then((data)=>{
            //res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=tokenized.txt');
            res.write(data, 'binary');
            res.end();
        }).catch((err)=>{
            res.redirect('/?err='+err);
        });

    });
```

This is the tokenizer.tokenizeFile code:

```
tokenizeFile: function(file, req){

        actionLogger.info(`Request to tokenize ${file.originalname} received. Made by: ${req.user.displayName}`);

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var fileProcessPromise = Promise.resolve();

            var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
                input: require('streamifier').createReadStream(file.buffer)
            });

            var output = "";

            lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
                //Tokenize each line

                if (!validate.validateLine(line)) return reject(`Invalid line [${line}].`);
                fileProcessPromise = Tokenize(line)
                .then((data)=>{
                    output += data + "\\r\\n";
                })
                .catch((err)=>{
                    reject(`API didn\'t respond.`);
                });
            });

            lineReader.on('close', () => {
                fileProcessPromise.then(()=>resolve(output));
            });

        });

    }
```

Tokenize function returns a promise as it is an HTTP request to a RESTful API.

Thing is that I need the output file to maintain the same order, and with the code above it will have the order depending on the speed the Tokenize function resolves.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you able to use async/await? it would simplify the code somewhat.

Comment: @spender I think I could... wouldn’t that freeze the app while it waits?

Comment: async/await is syntactic sugar on promise..then handling, so it will not freeze the app.

Comment: @num8er never used ir before (Im really new on all this..) where should i put it?

Comment: Fede, I don't think You've to complicate all the stuff. I think You can just read overall the file without using line by line.

Comment: ok. wait a bit I'm writing the code

Comment: @num8er but it's either using a foreach and splitting the file contents or processing line by line... As I need to "tokenize" each line by calling the HTTP api with each line... right?

Comment: Understood what You mean, so wait a bit

Comment: @num8er sure thing! :)

Comment: I agree, process the whole file in one go, maybe building an array of line items.  Then `for of` loop over using async/await for the HTTP requests to keep order.

Comment: How the solution should look like depends on the acutal usecase. If the uploaded file can be large, or if there can be a huge number of requests to your api, then you should think over a stream based apporach to process each line. If this is not a problem and it is ok to hold the whole file in memory, then you might creat an array of all lines first.

Comment: @t.niese I'm thinking about limiting the file to about 10K lines, which are a lot, but I need the user to be able to do about 10K lines per file.

Comment: Good point about memory use.  If you control the endpoint you are directing these requests to, it could be worthwhile to modify it for batch processing.  10k http requests for each go can be a lot depending on what the endpoint is and what kind of rate limiting they may enforce.

Comment: While the solutions that collect the Promises returned by `Tokenize` in an array will work, I still would suggest that you take a look at transform streams. Your described use-case can be implemented more memory and performance efficient using a stream-based approach.

Comment: @FedeE. have You checked my answer?

Comment: @num8er not yet, had to go out. Will do in a few hours. Will let you know. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Tokenize file code:

```
tokenizeFile: (file, req) => {

  actionLogger.info(`Request to tokenize ${file.originalname} received. Made by: ${req.user.displayName}`);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const lines = [], responses = [];

    const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: require('streamifier').createReadStream(file.buffer)
    });

    // 1. read all lines to array
    lineReader.on('line', line => {
      if(!validate.validateLine(line)) {
        return reject(`Invalid line [${line}].`);
      }
      lines.push(line);
    });


    lineReader.on('close', async () => {
      // 2. process every line sequentially
      try {
        for(const line of lines) {
          const response = await Tokenize(line);
          responses.push(response);
        }
        resolve(responses.join("\n"));
      }
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        reject("API didn't respond");
      });
    });

  });
}
```

2) And the request part:

```
app.post(
  '/tokenizeFile', 
  isLoggedIn, 
  upload.single('file'), 
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const file = req.file;

      if (!validator.validateFile(file)) {
        throw new Error('invalidFile');
      }

      const data = await tokenizer.tokenizeFile(file, req);

      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=tokenized.txt');
      res.write(data, 'binary');
      res.end();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.redirect('/?err='+error);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Nice! You could potentially remove the dependency and use async/await within a `for const line of lines` loop if you wanted.

Comment: @WilliamFleming oh :) I forgot to use

Comment: Nice update! The final version is very easy to follow.

Comment: @WilliamFleming async package is good, but I must say for today nodejs devs must use latest versions to be ready for changes.

Comment: @num8er I'm testing your solution right now, getting: TypeError: tokenizer.tokenizeFile(...).join is not a function

Comment: I fixed it moving the .join("\n") to the on('close') event, it works! Awesome, thanks!! I'll check the other answers as well, as adding parallel processing and being able to keep the order would be ideal for larger files.

Comment: @FedeE. Actually I wanted to use parallel processing, but I saw that You call reject on overall processing - so I made id sequential. But I would recommend to think about queueing the processing with doing some callback. But for particular question I can write parallelism if You want.

Comment: @num8er you have done an awesome job man! Can't ask you for more :) Thanks again!

Comment: @FedeE. Happy to be helpful. Pleasure to read it. Thanks (: p.s. it can be achieved by chunking lines array to 10 (processing limit) items per array groups and doing the same but with `Promise.all()`. (; Or You may use `async.parallelLimit ` (I'm talking about `async` module, google it)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a combination of the Promise API as well as async/await:

```
tokenizeFile: function(file, req) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        actionLogger.info(`Request to tokenize ${file.originalname} received. Made by: ${req.user.displayName}`);
        var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
            input: require('streamifier').createReadStream(file.buffer)
        });
        linePromises = [];
        var validationFailed = false;
        lineReader.on('line', line => {
            if (!validate.validateLine(line)) {
                //stop the lineReader if possible
                reject(`Invalid line [${line}].`);
                validationFailed = true;
            }
            if (!validationFailed) {
                linePromises.push(Tokenize(line));
            }
        });
        lineReader.on('close',async () => {
                var outputStrings = [];
                for (var linePromise of linePromises) {
                    var data = await linePromise;
                    outputStrings.push(data);
                }
                var output = outputStrings.join("");
                resolve(output);
        });
    });    
}
```

It works in 2 phases... first of all it issues all the request promises to the tokenizer and pushes these promises into an array (in the same order as the original lines).

When the lineReader finishes (`'close'`), we have an array of in-flight promises which over which we loop, awaiting each promise ***in-sequence*** and pushing the result of the promise into an array. When that's finished, we just concatenate the array into a big string and resolve the outer promise.

Comment: I had a brief perusal of the `linereader` package and found no obvious way of stopping it. Hence the requirement for a flag `validationFailed`, so that once we reject, we don't do any more work on subsequent callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

to use a stream to read the file without buffering it to disk, https://www.npmjs.com/package/multipart-read-stream

then to use line stream to split  into lines https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-transform
then use some parallel transform https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel-transform
then to write the result to the response

you may need to add stream.pause() and stream.resume on drain if it is not implemented in the stream modules. to handle large content on the fly.

maybe to use 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-chunkify
to make large chunks of write to stream. so it might be handled easier by maybe compression or other transfer tasks that handle large chunks better than small ones.

maybe to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/bufferedstream

```
// npm install -save express readline-transform pump multipart-read-stream parallel-transform 

var multipart = require('multipart-read-stream')
var pump = require('pump')
const ReadlineTransform = require('readline-transform');
var ParallelTransform = require('parallel-transform');
var express = require('express')


var app = express()

app.get("/",function (req, res, next) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple=""><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
})


app.post("/upload",function (req, res) {


  var multipartStream = multipart(req.headers, handler)

 // res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'}); pump(req, res);  return; // debug

  pump(req, multipartStream, function (err) {
    if (err) { res.end('server error'); return;}
    res.end()
  })



  var handled=false
  function handler (fieldname, file, filename) {
    // from example:
    //console.log('reading file ' + filename + ' from field ' + fieldname)
    //var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join('/tmp', filename))
    //pump(file, fileStream)

    if(handled) return;
    handled=true;

     // res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'}); pump(file, res);  return; // debug

    const transform = new ReadlineTransform({ skipEmpty: false });
    pump(file, transform)
    //res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'}); pump(transform, res);  return; // debug



    var first=true;
    // maybe:
    var parallel = ParallelTransform(10, {objectMode:false}, function(data, callback) { // 10 is the parallism level

            // this might be faster:
            //  if(first){
            //      first=false;
            //      callback(null, "transformed:"+data);     
            //  }
            //  else
            //      callback(null, "\r\n"+"transformed:"+data);


        (async()=>{

            if(first){
                first=false;
                return "transformed:"+data;
            }
            else
            {               
                return "\r\n"+"transformed:"+data;
            }

        })().then( (data)=>callback(null,data) ).catch(  (error)=>callback(error,"") )


    });
    pump(transform, parallel)
    //res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'}); pump(parallel, res);  return; // debug




    pump(parallel, res)

  }

}).listen(8080)
```